# How to keep persistant SSH sessions?

Tags: ssh

There's a server I'd like to be connected to at all times that I have an internet connection. Sometimes I turn off my laptop, sometimes my connection drops, sometimes I go from wired to wireless or vice versa. Is there any solution to get it to automatically reconnect whenever possible and resume my screen session?

Comment: Are you running windows or linux on your laptop?

Comment: Linux Please enter at least 15 characters

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that autossh, possibly with a little bit of scripting to automatically reconnect to the screen session, will be the way to go.

Comment: Telling ssh to execute 'screen -DR' at the remote host is likely to be sufficient.

Comment: You'll probably want to throw a -t at SSH, in that case, but yeah I think that'll work.

Comment: screen, definitely.

Comment: @Steve Lacey: Huh?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider running ssh in a wrapper script.

```
#!/bin/sh
while ! ssh "$@"; do
   echo "Reconnecting..." >/dev/stderr
done
```

Call the script "ssh-forever" and use it with, for example:

```
$ ssh-forever -t user@host screen -DR
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like autossh already does this. It might be better to use that instead of rolling your own script.

http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it myself, but **if** I remember my hearsay correctly, Putty Tray will do that http://putty-tray.en.softonic.com/

Please comment if I'm wrong and leading John down the wrong path.

Comment: Looks like a good solution for windows clients.

Comment: D'oh! I missed John's comment above about it being a linux box. Thanks for subtly remarking that, pgs ;)

Answer (score -1):

screen command is what you need, you can attach or detach to the terminal from different locations:

http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen

Comment: I suspect that the OP already knows about screen, given that he said "resume my screen session"...

Comment: His original question already says "and resume my screen session".  What he wants is a client that will do automatic reconnects when the connection is lost.